# Format to highlight cell in Column D if value less than Column C

Tags: conditional-formatting

new here and sorry if this has been answered. I have searched for the formula but can't get it to work for me.

I have a tracking sheet that I want to have a cell in column D "red, and bold font" if the adjacent cell in C is more "ie. if C is 4, and D is 3, highlight the cell"

As mentioned, I've tried all the suggestions and it either doesn't work, or tells me I can't use conditional formatting for the range or something.

If someone could please provide the formula to put in that would be great.

I have the below two formulas already active, not sure if they're preventing it from working?
[Columns being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl4Jk.png)

[current rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEjpg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer in another post.

[WORKED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5a4h.png)

Comment: Please add some details. Providing just a link is not good form. You can always provide a link, but some indication of what the solution is, must be provided.